# Quaternion Division

Tags: quaternions

If $q$ and $r$ are quaternions, and $p$ is a point, applying $q$ then $r$ to $p$ is:

$$
(qr)p\dfrac{1}{qr}
$$

What if I want to go the other way? Instead of concatenating rotations, I want to remove them.

So, I have $q$ and $m$, and I know that $qx =m$, but I don't know what $x$ is. How can I discover $x$? (How can I do quaternion division?)

Answer (score 6):

In algebra, multiplication is denoted by juxtaposition, not by an asterisk.
The inverse of the operation $p\mapsto qpq^{-1}$ is $p\mapsto q^{-1}pq$.
The solution of $qx=m$ is $x=q^{-1}m$. Note that
$$(a+bi+cj+dk)^{-1}=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^{-1}(a-bi-cj-dk).$$

All this can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

Answer (score 3):

I would note that the situation is similar to matrix multiplication: since multiplication here is noncommutative, you have to distinguish between "premultiplying" with the inverse $p^{-1}q$ and "postmultiplying" with the inverse $qp^{-1}$.

Note also that

$$(q\cdot r)^{-1}=r^{-1}\cdot q^{-1}$$

The only other thing I can say is that what you're essentially doing is the quaternion analog of a "similarity transformation" of a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) under the section Conjugation, the norm, and reciprocal.  You just need the reciprocal of q.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of quaternion division also applies to complex numbers and real numbers. If I write a quaternion as a scalar and a three vector like so:
$q=(s,\vec{V})$, then the inverse is $q^{-1}=(s,-\vec{V})/(s^2 + V \cdot V)$. For the reals, the inverse is 1/s. I agree with other posters that writing 1/q is in error. The 1/x notation is fine so long as one's algebra commutes, which is true for the real and complex numbers which are subgroups of quaternions.